# Laravel Lighthouse EnsureXHR middleware gets in the way of file upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I've taken the example from the Lighthouse(v6) documentation for [uploading a file](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/file-uploads.html#setup).

1. Added the mutation

```
type Mutation { upload(file: Upload!): String }
```

2. Then create a custom `Upload` mutation class

```
final readonly class Upload
{
    /** @param  array{}  $args */
    public function __invoke(null $_, array $args)
    {
        dd($args);
    }
}
```

Went on to write the first test

```
public function upload_profile_photo_successfully(): void
    {
        $operations = [
            'query' => /** @lang GraphQL */ '
        mutation ($file: Upload!) {
            upload(file: $file)
        }
    ',
            'variables' => [
                'file' => null,
            ],
        ];

        $map = [
            '0' => ['variables.file'],
        ];

        $file = [
            '0' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('test.pdf', 500),
        ];
        $user = $this->createRandomUser()->getUser();
        $this->actingAs($user);

        $this->multipartGraphQL($operations, $map, $file)->dd();
    }
```

When I run the test the `EnsureXHR` middleware throws the exception

```
Content-Type multipart/form-data; is forbidden
```

which is expected from the middleware code

```
public const FORM_CONTENT_TYPES = [
   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'multipart/form-data',
   'text/plain',
];

...

if (Str::startsWith($contentType, static::FORM_CONTENT_TYPES)) {
   throw new BadRequestHttpException("Content-Type {$contentType} is forbidden");
}
```

**How can I do the file upload with the XHR in place?**

I tried deactivating the XHR middleware and it works fine, but that's not what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the [middleware code](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/e97a9c0715d25f080ff915f1c62e494426797ba3/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureXHR.php#L36-L38) I can see the following:

```php
if ($request->header('X-Requested-With', '') === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    return $next($request);
}
```

So the solution is to add the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header to your request to allow your request to pass the `EnsureXHR` middleware.

Alternatively, remove the `EnsureXHR` middleware when running your test suite since it makes no sense to force only XHR requests when testing unless you are doing browser testing.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. You're right on the money, I ended up disabling the XHR.